# Multiple handler loop Android

Tags: android, loops, handler

I am trying to design a program that makes multiple API calls on a website (Each "name" has several modes that I have to loop through before I move on to the next name).  The problem is, you are limited to calling the API once every second.  I thought the handler was the way to go but now I don't think so.

It runs through the loop just fine but I don't think so.  I get the following error:

EDIT: Figured out that this was being caused by

```
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f050002
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:459)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at com.companionfree.flurryanalytics.APICallData.doInBackground(APICallData.java:66)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at com.companionfree.flurryanalytics.APICallData.doInBackground(APICallData.java:1)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-21 22:33:46.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9683):     ... 4 more
```

When I make this call in my Asynchronous task:

> String[] metrics = r.getStringArray(R.array.metric_apicall);

I don't think my code is designed right for what I am trying to do.  Can anyone tell me if this is the right approach?...Also, APICallData(MainActivity.this, app, mode).execute(); is an asynchronous task.

```
//Other code above this irrelevant

    mApp = 0;
    mMode = 0;
    callAPI(mMode, names[mApp]);
    mMode++;

    while (mApp < names.length) {
        while (mMode < metrics.length) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                    callAPI(mMode, names[mApp]);

                }
            }, 1010); 
            mMode++;
        }
        mMode = 0;
        mApp++;
    }

private void callAPI(int mode, String app) {
    new APICallData(MainActivity.this, app, mode).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Timer and TimerTask and exeute it with an interval of 1 sec.

Comment: Won't that freeze up the whole process though?  I need it to be a background update...

Comment: Straight from java Docs.....  Timer is a facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.
Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks.  Hope this helps clearing your doubts